# Show element in scroll list using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, show

I have a diagram of the floor plan and photos on it are the employees. The right side has the names of the employees. Photos and names of associated ID. The number of names of employees very much. And it does not fit on the page. Scrolling list. I need to when you click on the photo officer. Shows the person's name on the page

```
<img class="avatar" src="personal_ava.png" avatar-id="53" style="left: 445px; top: 425px;">
<div class="employee-descr" employee-id="53">Test T.T</div>
```

I already have a page of photos and names. I need to when you click on the photo automatically scrolling and showed the name

Comment: It can be set to the employee photo circuit. And his name on the bottom of the list, and when you can not see the flashing employee name

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're looking for something like this:

```
<style>
    .employee-desc { display: none; }
</style>

<script>
    $(function()
    {
        $(".avatar").click(function()
        {
            var el = $(this).next();
            // or $("div[data-employee-id='"+$(this).attr("data-avatar-id")+"']").toggle();
            el.toogle();
            $("html, body").animate({
                scrollTop: el.offset().top,
                scrollLeft: el.offset().left
            }, 0);
        });
    });
</script>

<img class="avatar" src="personal_ava.png" data-avatar-id="53" style="left: 445px; top: 425px;" />
<div class="employee-desc" data-employee-id="53">Test T.T</div>
```

Comment: it's different. I already have a page of photos and names. I need to when you click on the photo automatically scrolling and showed the name

Comment: It scrolls the page. I need to scroll lists emploee

Comment: Then use `$(emploee list).css({top: x, left: y})`. Sorry, I can't understand what you want, and you haven't posted the full code of your site.